# AnimationSet issue in android

Tags: android, animation

I'm using AnimationSet to perform a sequence of TranslateAnimations.

```
    icon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);

    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    TranslateAnimation slide1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 50, 0, 100); 
    slide1.setStartOffset(0);
    slide1.setDuration(800);
    animationSet.addAnimation(slide1);

    TranslateAnimation slide2 = new TranslateAnimation(50, 100, 100, -100); 
    slide2.setStartOffset(1000);
    slide2.setDuration(800);
    animationSet.addAnimation(slide2);
....

    animationSet.setFillAfter(true);
    icon.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

My problem is that the animation is very jerky. The first animation occurs very abruptly, then the second one starts. How can I make this smooth & even?

Answer (score 5):

create xml file for animation and try this

```
            AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    Animation AnimFirst = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(act, R.anim.first);
    Animation rAnimSecond = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(act, R.anim.second);
    animSet.addAnimation(AnimFirst);
    animSet.addAnimation(AnimSecond);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    icon.clearAnimation();
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    icon.startAnimation(animSet);
```

animFirst.xml

```
       <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="2000" android:fillAfter="true" />
      </set>
```

u must change value whatever u want..

Comment: can u show me the basic structure of the xml. I tried creating a file under res/anim but getting "Multiple annotations found at this line.." error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the higher duration for animations (>= 1500).

Comment: UI animations are experienced as annoying for the user if they take too long, especially if they happen often in your app. Android design guidelines say 300ms is an ideal length for small UI animations, depending on the kind of animation.